# Поиск песен в PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, аудио, pyqt

Есть код, надо сделать, там 2 кнопки. Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на список песен, переходило так сказать в новое окно, и там появлялась возможность ввести название песни, когда вводишь, он выдаёт эту песню.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class Guitar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.Accords_button = QPushButton('список клипов', self)
        self.Accords_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Accords_button.move(300, 500)

        self.Songs_button = QPushButton('список песен', self)
        self.Songs_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Songs_button.move(300, 200)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap('12.jpg')
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.move(650, 2)
        self.image.resize(600, 900)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Guitar()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: тебе надо создать виджет, который будет открываться по нажатию на кнопку. Код за вас никто писать не будет

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Просто я пока не сильно разбираюсь, пишу как могу. У меня не получается реализовать сам поисковик, переход вроде получилось сделать. А вот ка кзагрузить базу данных и тд, я не знаю, чтоб я вводил название песен, и выдавало эту песню: например текст песни и ещё что-нибудь, например аккорды.